# Upgrading Rails app on Heroku from Ruby 3.2.2 to Ruby 3.3.0 causes large slug size increase resulting in slug size too large build error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

The Rails app deployed to https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/empora-rails-staging is currently configured via `.ruby-version` and `Gemfile` to use Ruby version `3.2.2`. When configured as such, the resultant compressed slug size according to the [build log](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/empora-rails-staging/activity/builds/16206a9e-9e34-4fe6-af6d-b41e0c9c9232) is as follows:

```
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 178.6M
```

After changing the Ruby version to `3.3.0` inside `.ruby-version` and `Gemfile` and deploying the branch with those changes, the build fails because the slug size according to [this build log](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/empora-rails-staging/activity/builds/68b74eca-e016-40f2-b2e2-01e6e65be78b) is now well over the limit of 500 MB.

```
-----> Compressing...
 !     Compiled slug size: 559.6M is too large (max is 500M).
```

I've tried some things to reduce the compiled slug size but nothing is making a significant difference.

It seems odd to me that a Ruby upgrade would result in such a significant compiled slug size difference causing this app to be too large.

I would like to understand why the Ruby upgrade is behaving in this manner. Is there anything I can do inside my app's build to see the files/details of the compiled slug that is now over 500 MB?

Comment: Your application on Heroku and its build log are not visible to people who aren't a member of your team. Would you, therefore, mind sharing the build log in your question? And what build-pack do you have configured in your application?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered why this is happening. Prior to the Ruby 3.3. upgrade, `Gemfile.lock` contains platform specific versions of `grpc` as follows:

```
    grpc (1.60.0-arm64-darwin)
       google-protobuf (~> 3.25)
       googleapis-common-protos-types (~> 1.0)
     grpc (1.60.0-x86_64-darwin)
       google-protobuf (~> 3.25)
       googleapis-common-protos-types (~> 1.0)
     grpc (1.60.0-x86_64-linux)
```

The platform specific versions of `grpc` are currently not compatible with Ruby 3.3 (see [this issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/35396).

Consequently, I am now including a single `grpc` dependency which requires it to be built during a Heroku deployment. This results in `bundle install` on Heroku downloading the complete source for `grpc` which is over 2 GB.

Once the platform specific versions of `grpc` are made compatible with Ruby 3.3, I'll be able to switch back and resolve this slug size issue.